# Fill rows of a partially filled array with numbers VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

The problem I'm trying to solve is pretty simple theoretically, but I'm really struggling to put in into VBA code. 
Basically, my problem is: The user inputs file containing a number at the beginning, this will be read as n, and a matrix that is read into an array, of size nxn, that has been partially filled, I need to fill each row with the numbers 1 to n, having each number appear only once. I need to do this for each row in the given array.

So, I need to look through each row, see what numbers it contains and fill in the blanks with the numbers it does not contain.

Here is the bulk of my code:

```VBA
Sub Problem()

    'Define the variables
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim inputFileName As String

    'Ask the user for the input file name
    inputFileName = InputBox("Enter Problem Filename (include .txt extension)")
    inputFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & inputFileName
    Open inputFileName For Input As #1

    'Read in the variable n at the top of the file
    Input #1, n

    'Construct the (n x n) matrix that will hold the problem and read in the problem from the input file
    ReDim Matrix(1 To n, 1 To n) As Integer
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To n
            Input #1, Matrix(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    Close #1

    '**************************************************************
    'Make a random starting solution
    ReDim sol(1 To n, 1 To n) As Integer
    initialSolution sol, Matrix, n

End Sub
```

I'm using a small subprocedure called initialSolution that gets an initial solution, however this is the part I am stuck on. Here is the very basic outline of the Sub, I haven't filled it in:

```
Sub initialSolution(sol() As Integer, Matrix() As Integer, n As Integer)

End Sub
```

Comment: Ignore the variable sol() this is for another part of the question which I haven't mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
Dim Counter: Counter = 1
Dim f, i
n = 15 'n=InputBox return
For f = 1 To n
    For i = 1 To n
        Cells(f, i).Value = Counter
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next
Next
```